# add class to parent element if conditions are true, test not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Building on the answer to "add class to parent element if conditions are true", I set the following:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <style>
    .zero {background:#900;color:white;}
  </style>
</head>

<div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</p>0</p></td>
    <td>2</p>10</p></td>
    <td>3</p>0</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<script>
$() {
  $('p', 'table').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() ==='0') {
    $(this).parents("td").addClass("zero");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

I used this in the answers jsfiddle example and it worked fine.  I've only added the `$() { });` in place of the 'onload' offered in the jsfiddle.  In my example the td containing a p with text exactly equalling '0' does not take the styling.  Ideas welcome.

Comment: `$() { ... });` doesn't look like JavaScript. What is it? edit: Did you mean `$(function () { ... });`?

Comment: also code shows `</p>0</p>` instead of `<p>0</p>`

Comment: Could you show us the link to jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your opening paragraph tags in the table are wrong, and you need to put your script in an event like an on ready or the like.

Table:

```
<td>1<p>0</p></td>
<td>2<p>10</p></td>
<td>3<p>0</p></td>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p', 'table').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() ==='0') {
            $(this).parents("td").addClass("zero");
        }
    });
});
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/h7kyv9z6/

Comment: Always the basic stuff that trips me up.  Quality answer.